# Can't find Bluetooth file

Tags: sound, files, bluetooth, pulseaudio, find

This may sound dumb, but i have searched everywhere for /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf . I cannot find it. I have tried searching and doing everything of the manner, but I cannot find it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It should literary be in /etc/bluetooth, what is your output of `ls /etc/bluetooth`?

I just ran the same command and it resided in the /etc/bluetooth folder.

Edit: you might also run `whereis bluetooth.conf` from the terminal or open nautilus and navigate to your root folder "/" (this is necessary because nautilus searches recursively)  and then search with the search tool in nautilus (select location: filesystem).